# range_value_t for reference type

Tags: c++, c++20

I was playing with C++ 20 ranges and noticed something weird (reproducible at https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4Ycxn88qa):

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <ranges>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    using KV = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;

    std::vector<KV> v;
    auto r = v | std::views::filter([](const KV& kv) { return kv.first == "foo"; })
               | std::views::transform([](const KV& kv) -> const std::string& { return kv.second; });

    for (auto&& val : r) {
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(val), const std::string&>);
    }

    using R = decltype(r);
    using Elem = std::ranges::range_value_t<R>;

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<Elem, std::string>);  // success
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<Elem, const std::string&>);  // error
}
```

I expected the last `static_assert` to succeed and the second to last to fail, but the reverse is true. Why?

**UPDATE:** Apparently `range_reference_t` gives me what I need:

```cpp
static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::ranges::range_reference_t<R>, const std::string&>); // ok
```

Is `range_value_t` supposed to always give me a decayed type?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is `range_value_t` supposed to always give me a decayed type?

The `value_type` of an iterator (and, consequently, a range) should always be a *cv*-unqualified type, yes. That's just the way that the model works. This isn't really specified in the standard library anywhere to my knowledge, but you can see that the `value_type` of `T*` is `remove_cv_t<T>` ([[iterators.iterator.traits]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterators#iterator.traits-5)) or that the way we get the `value_type` of `transform_view`'s iterators is by doing a `remove_cvref_t` on the `reference` type ([[range.transform.iterator]](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.transform.iterator)).

`reference`, on the other hand, is the type that you get when you dereference the iterator - literally `decltype(*it)`. Unfortunately, this one is confusingly named because `reference` is not necessarily a language type.

For instance, `int*` is basically the simplest iterator: its `value_type` is `int` while its `reference` is `int&`. Similarly, for `int const*`, the `value_type` is the same (still `int`) while the `reference` changes (to `int const&`).